# Which is the most stable way to install flutter in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, flutter, snapcraft, arch

I recently decided to switch from W10 to GNU/Linux, and yes still a Linux noob.

So which is the most recommended way to install flutter on Linux?, **a way which won't get me troubles in the future when I try to update flutter.**

Right now I only now this three ways, which one is the best option? (you're free to tell me is there is another and better option)

- Install Flutter using **snapcraft** (snapd)
- Install Flutter **manually** with github repo or tar
- Install Flutter using **yay** (Arch-based distros only)

*I really don't know anything about flutter in GNU/Linux so, I'd appreciate any opinion and advice.
Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and most stable for me was manually, but not from gitHub, by using tar.
SnapD caused errors, but using .tar has been fine for 5 months now. Updating easily and seamlessly.
As you may have seen, but follow the documentation here step by step will work fine.
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux
If you have trouble exporting the path, come back for further help.
Welcome to the club.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, you've saved me from a lot of troubles cuz I was planning to installing flutter with snapd, I'll upvote you when I get enough reputation.

Comment: You're most welcome, rep will give in time. If you go through with this and things are fine for you as well, kindly mark it as an answer. Happy coding.